# expected 'int' but argument is of type 'char *'

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I wanted to make program that asks user to input three numbers and say which of those three numbers is the biggest. It throws same error for all three numbers: "passing argument 1 of 'max' makes integer from pointer without a cast" and "expected 'int' but argument is of type 'char *' ". Also when it says "Type first number: " and when I type it doesn't say "Type second number: " but just ends program.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int max (int num1, int num2, int num3)
{       
    printf("Type number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", num1);
    printf("Type number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", num2);
    printf("Type number 3: ");
    scanf("%d", num3);


    int result;
    if(num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
    {
        result = num1;
    }

    else if(num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
    {
        result = num2; 
    }
    else
    {
        result = num3;
    }    
}


int main()
{

    printf("%f", max("%f", "%f", "%f"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max("%f", "%f", "%f")`..that's not how C works!

Comment: Why are you passing `"%f"` to `max`? What do you expect that to do? And `scanf` needs a pointer not an `int`.

Comment: Many, many problems here.  Most have to do with type mismatches, using integers where pointers are needed, and using pointers where integers are needed.  *Be consistent*.  If a function argument has type `int`, then you must *pass* an `int`.  For example, `"%f"` is not an int.  It's a character string, and when passed as a function argument, it has type `char *`.  But `int` and `char *` are not compatible.  So don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems, comments in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(void) // No parameters
{
    int num1, num2, num3; // we place the variables at local scope

    printf("Type number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1); // scanf wants a pointer
    printf("Type number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Type number 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &num3);

    int result;

    if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
    {
        result = num1;
    }
    else if(num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
    {
        result = num2; 
    }
    else
    {
        result = num3;
    }
    return result; // you need to return the value, otherwise main doesn't know the result
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", max()); // use %d as specifier and call max without arguments

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any argument to `max()`.

- Reduce the function definition to

  ```
  float max (void) { //.....
  ```
- Define `num1`, `num2` and `num3` as local variable inside `max()`.
- and call it like

  ```
  printf("%f", max());
  ```

Note: I hope you noticed the return type of the function is also changed.

Answer (score 0):

In C, we make functions which take arguments. You have declared your function so that it takes three integers as arguments, and you have then called it inside your Main function.

The compiler looks at the declaration you have provided

```
int max (int num1, int num2, int num3)
```

and it deduces that you should pass the function three integer values.

You than call the function inside your main like so:

```
printf("%f", max("%f", "%f", "%f"));
```

Now the compiler looks at max("%f", "%f", "%f") and deduces that you are calling it with three string arguments. It looks back at the declaration and sees that you told it that you expect ints, and so it tells you that it cannot call your function, as it doesn't know how to turn the strings into ints.

With this in mind, how can we fix the code to work the way you intended?

1. first of all, ask yourself what your function needs. There are two ways of doing this which can work for your situation - either you will get the values inside the main function and then pass them to the function

In this case, the function declaration stays the same.

```
int a, b, c;

scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
int result = max(a, b, c);
```

The second option is to not pass anything to the function and just let it read the numbers from the user. In that case you would declare the function like this:

```
int max(){
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    // rest of your code
}
```

2. When using printf, make sure to use the appropriate format string. "%f" tells the compiler you would like to print your number as a floating point number, meaning it will be printed as .0 (for example, 3.0). If you are printing integers, use "%d".
3. Finally, make sure to read the documentation. It will save you a lot of trouble. :)

Comment: I really appreciate you explaining it this way. Thank you for all the advices and your time.